# Stop TortoiseSVN from tracking my desktop

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

I didn't use TortoiseSVN much in university and hasn't used it since graduation until recently. The first and only time I touched it at work, I was trying to remember how to use it. I don't remember what I did but now TortoiseSVN is tracking my Desktop folder so I can see a red icon on my Desktop in the File Explorer (you know, that icon that indicates the folder is not synced with the repo).

It was never intended for the Desktop to be part of my project team's repo, I was just messing around. So I want to remove that icon i.e. stop TortoiseSVN from tracking my Desktop permanently. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the hidden .svn folder from your desktop

Comment: Thanks, never knew there's such a folder or that that's how TortoiseSVN works. TIL!

Answer (score 2):

Delete hidden folder ".svn" on your Desktop.